# Getting RestEASY, HIbernate, Maven and JBossAS5.1 to play nicely

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jboss5.x

I'm trying to build a restful webservice that uses hibernate for data access.  I am using Maven to build and have to deploy on JBossAS5.1 - probably EAP5.x in future.

RestEASY is fine, but I'm having issues with Hibernate, as soon as I add hibernate dependencies to pom.xml the resulting WAR crashes immediately after deploy.

I'm reasonably comfortable with Java and Maven but am new to JavaEE beyond simple JSP.

pom.xml extract:

```
      <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>jboss</id>
              <name>jboss repo</name>
              <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
          </repository>
      </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>  
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>          

    </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
              </exclusion> 
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
              </exclusion> 
          </exclusions> 
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
           <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions> 
      </dependency>

  <build>
    <finalName>hedgehog-rest</finalName>
    <plugins> 
        <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
            <configuration> 
                <source>1.6</source> 
                <target>1.6</target> 
            </configuration> 
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I removed all my code except this class:

```
@Path("/echo")
public class Echo 
{
    @GET
    @Produces("text/*")
    @Path("/{message}")
    public Response echoService(@PathParam("message") String message)
    {
        return Response.status(200).entity(message).build();
    }
}
```

Beginning of error log below:

```
20:37:05,848 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/hedgehog-rest
20:37:06,956 INFO  [ConfigurationBootstrap] Adding scanned resource: com.ecs.hedgehog.Echo
20:37:07,057 ERROR [[/hedgehog-rest]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:36)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
```

Comment: hmmm, seems to work ok with <scope>provided</scope> added to the hibernate dependency ... experimenting

Answer (score 1):

yup Hibernate JARs being included by Maven were conflicting with those in JBossAS.  Discovered dependency scope: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Solved! :-)